# Luis not working due to its maintance (just in spanish culture)?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

our staging application with spanish culture was not working yesterday, and today our production application is also not working. The problem is that  some intents are not returning any entities. And in the web of luis is annunced that "We are performing system wide maintenance. Some apps may experience temporary unavailability. Thank you for your patience."

We want to know if it is a normal case and how long will it last. Our bot is in the production, which means it is a product. We ara caring about our product, and do not want interrupt its service with any accident.

Also we want to know is there any technical way to avoiding cases like this.

Detail of the error, when call version english https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/xxxx?subscription-key=xxxxxxxxxx&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=malaga

```
        {
      "query": "malaga",
      "topScoringIntent": {
        "intent": "sports_football_team_global",
        "score": 0.989564657
      },
      "intents": [
        {
          "intent": "sports_football_team_global",
          "score": 0.989564657
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_follow",
          "score": 0.256285429
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_unfollow",
          "score": 0.0624738075
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_football_team_information",
          "score": 0.0452761
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_notification_level",
          "score": 0.0250913966
        },
        {
          "intent": "OPTA_Cancelar",
          "score": 0.01700071
        },
        {
          "intent": "None",
          "score": 0.0113976067
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_enable_notification",
          "score": 0.01062314
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_emotion_hate",
          "score": 0.008717464
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_competition_classification",
          "score": 0.006895263
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_welcome",
          "score": 0.003931297
        },
        {
          "intent": "root_change_user_info",
          "score": 0.002939801
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_disable_notification",
          "score": 0.00284402771
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_team_last_match",
          "score": 0.002589234
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_next_match_bytime",
          "score": 0.00225439551
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_showmore_team",
          "score": 0.00210961024
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_competition_next_round",
          "score": 0.00183723459
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_team_next_match",
          "score": 0.0017626757
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_competition_last_round",
          "score": 0.001716528
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_emotion_gol",
          "score": 0.001380223
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_unfollow_all",
          "score": 0.00104989111
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_current_match",
          "score": 0.0008975425
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_last_match",
          "score": 0.0005386151
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_show_follow",
          "score": 0.0004062014
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_team_current_match",
          "score": 0.000116936135
        },
        {
          "intent": "sports_user_next_match",
          "score": 1.70625044E-05
        }
      ],
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "malaga",
          "type": "football_team",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 5,
          "resolution": {
            "values": [
              "Málaga"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

And version spanish https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/xxxxxx?subscription-key=xxxx&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=malaga

```
{
  "query": "malaga",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "sports_football_team_global",
    "score": 0.9602209
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "sports_football_team_global",
      "score": 0.9602209
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_disable_notification",
      "score": 0.130784482
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_team_last_match",
      "score": 0.09194096
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_notification_level",
      "score": 0.08853955
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_team_next_match",
      "score": 0.0597797334
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_unfollow",
      "score": 0.0510462932
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_football_team_information",
      "score": 0.0401076
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_competition_classification",
      "score": 0.03524222
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_follow",
      "score": 0.02526744
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_next_match_bytime",
      "score": 0.0111262156
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_enable_notification",
      "score": 0.009637802
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_team_current_match",
      "score": 0.00436334638
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_emotion_hate",
      "score": 0.004245238
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.00323706563
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_show_follow",
      "score": 0.00276356842
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_showmore_team",
      "score": 0.00234427629
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_last_match",
      "score": 0.00233005267
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_welcome",
      "score": 0.00157872075
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_competition_next_round",
      "score": 0.00108685123
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_emotion_gol",
      "score": 0.000902815256
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_competition_last_round",
      "score": 0.000205698016
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_current_match",
      "score": 0.000102570972
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_next_match",
      "score": 3.606828E-05
    },
    {
      "intent": "sports_user_unfollow_all",
      "score": 3.43515676E-05
    }
  ],
  "entities": []
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this inconvenience ahll, are you still running into this issue? If so, can you please provide the app ID for the Spanish application?

Comment: We have published a new version with cloning of the failed version, and all the thing go well. If you want to check what happed, I am glad to send your our app id.

Answer (score 0):

It was a temporary issue which has been **resolved**. Please contact Luisuservoice@microsoft.com if any issues.